# gensim Latent Dirichlet Allocation minimum_probability vs print_topics

Tags: python, lda, gensim

My question is related to this post, [Document topical distribution in Gensim LDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310933/document-topical-distribution-in-gensim-lda), the documentation for gensim.models.ldamodel states that "minimum_probability controls filtering the topics returned for a document (bow)." however, ldamodel[corpus] returns all possible topics with their probability (even below the number set in minimum_probability). what is the difference between these two? 
python 2.7.5
gensim 0.13.3

thank you

Comment: similar issue is raised in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36967532/5031727 but unlike the comment ldamodel[corpus] produces tuple of id and topics that are below the value set in min probability.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of [the documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html) is that `minimum_probability` can be both the parameter of the model generation (applied to all queries afterwards) and the querying interface, e.g. `get_document_topics(bow, minimum_probability=None, ....)`. So unless you trained with the `minimum_probability` parameter `model[doc_bow]` would not trim on probability.